# What is the verse spoken at the end of the movie

Tags: dialogue, song-of-bernadette

In the movie "Song of Bernadette" what is the verse being spoken in the background by a priest at her death?

Comment: Welcome to the community. Would you be able to add a clip to this question?

Answer (score 1):

It's the [**Song of Solomon Chap.2 Verse 10**](https://www.bible.com/en-GB/bible/114/sng.2.10-13.nkjv) (although precise translations vary)

> Behold my beloved speaketh to me, arise make haste my love, my dove, my beautiful one ...

Google Books extract

[image]